# Difference between BigInteger.probablePrime() and other primality algorithms in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, biginteger

I am implementing an RSA encryption program using Java. Right now I am using   `BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, rnd)` to get prime numbers.  Here `rnd` is a random number generated by `Random rnd = new Random()` . 
I need to test various speeds of encryption.

My questions are:

1. what algorithm does the `BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, rnd)` use?
2. what is the difference between the algorithm above and other algorithms:  like Rabin-Miller, Fermats, Lucas-Lehmer?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you specify the language? I'm presuming Java, but presumptions... It would not hurt to read your post and remove errors before posting either.

Comment: Apologies, yes java. And by errors i presume you mean the way i state bigint. I tried to shorthand it I do understand that is not how to use the method in java

Comment: I'm aware that not everybody will be able to write English at the same level, but if even the methods are spelled wrong, it will be hard to look up anything from that. Also, please use the code tags for methods. If you cannot spell 
"BigInteger.probablePrime()", you could revert to copy/pasting it from the online JavaDoc. Now it *looks* like you are not spending any time on the question, and we will return the favor of not spending any time on the answer.

Comment: Once again I apologize for not responding and a caring manner. This is my first post and I am not familiar with the syntax and manner in which i am to write my questions. It has been noted for future reference.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to that, all my links were badly written so far. Meta stackoverflow has lots of useful tips about markup. And you can hit [edit] on your question and check the changes from mikej.

Comment: Old question, but just in case anyone else is doing something similar you should use Java's `SecureRandom` class. `Random` is a PRNG and has no guarantee that it will be random enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigInteger`'s probable prime methods use both the Miller-Rabin and Lucas-Lehmer algorithms to test primality.

See the internal method [`BigInteger.primeToCertainty`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html).

Comment: That seems to be the right answer. Do we know the name of the algorithm is behind the bit sieve used for primes > 95 bits?

Comment: `BitSieve` calls back into `BigInteger.primeToCertainty`.

Comment: Ah, that was probably (pardon the pun) to be expected, thanks Michael, hadn't found that out yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! and thank you for the link to the source code. Much appreciated for all your help. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 2):

The Java source code is available for download, so you can look at it yourself. 
 Here is the code for `BigInteger.probablePrime(int, Random)`:

```
public static BigInteger probablePrime(int bitLength, Random rnd) {

    if (bitLength < 2)
        throw new ArithmeticException("bitLength < 2");

    // The cutoff of 95 was chosen empirically for best performance

    return (bitLength < SMALL_PRIME_THRESHOLD ?
            smallPrime(bitLength, DEFAULT_PRIME_CERTAINTY, rnd) :
            largePrime(bitLength, DEFAULT_PRIME_CERTAINTY, rnd));
}
```

The actual tests are contained in the `smallPrime()` and  `largePrime()` methods, which follow directly in the source code.

Comment: Both those methods call passesMillerRabin() and passesLucasLehmer(), through the primeToCertainty() method, at least in the OpenJDK 1.7 source that has been linked by Michael. For large primes (> 95 bits) a BitSieve is used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! and thank you for the link to the source code. Much appreciated for all your help. Have a wonderful day.