# Java BigInteger prime generation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math

BigInteger in Java has constructor that generates prime numbers, I cant find any mention of what algorithm is used in this. Is there a name of algorithm or maybe a book where this algorithm described?

Comment: I looked in source code, there is no mention of algorithm source or name either

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744085/difference-between-biginteger-probableprime-and-other-primality-algorithms

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744085/difference-between-biginteger-probableprime-and-other-primality-algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

> It is recommended that the probablePrime
>   method be used in preference to this constructor unless there is a
>   compelling need to specify a certainty. - *from [Java 7 BigInteger API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random))*

Having said that. BigInteger's probable prime methods use both the Miller-Rabin and Lucas-Lehmer algorithms to test primality.

See passesMillerRabin(rounds, random) && passesLucasLehmer(); in [BigInteger internal method primeToCertainty from java 7](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html).

Further reading on:

1. [Miller-Rabin primality test (Java)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Miller-Rabin_primality_test_(Java))
2. [Lucas-Lehmer test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Lucas-Lehmer_test#Java)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used is an implementation detail that may vary from jdk to jdk, even between versions. The contract is only that it gives you a prime number, not that it follows any given algorithm to do so.