# Why does Java BigInteger say 'probably prime' and not 'certainly prime'?

Tags: java, biginteger

The JavaDoc of BigInteger makes me feel very insecure, for example the following constructor says:

```
BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)
```

> Constructs a randomly generated positive BigInteger that is probably
>   prime, with the specified bitLength.

Why only probably? Why not certainly? Can I still trust that the result would be a prime number?

Comment: Did you read [the detailed section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random))? The increasing runtime is why only probably. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8744085/3001761

Comment: It's only probably because it uses a prime testing algorithm that may fail. The rest of the documentation provides an upper bound on the probability of failure.

Comment: There is an algorithm due to Maurer that find primes that are guaranteed to be prime. See for example [this](https://programmingpraxis.com/2017/03/31/generating-random-large-primes/) problem. This algorithm is not currently available in the Java runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20int,%20java.util.Random)) for `BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)`:

> `certainty`: a measure of the uncertainty that the caller is
>            willing to tolerate.  The probability that the new BigInteger
>            represents a prime number will exceed
>            (1 - ½<sup>certainty</sup>).  The execution time of
>            this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.

So the constructor lets you specify the certainty that it will be prime, which is why the docs say "probably"

Answer (score 5):

Because the probabilistic algorithm runs a lot faster than verifying that the number is definitely prime.